# Difference results of SQL query execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I execute this queries several times right one after the other, but the first time the result is the same, but the remaining times it is different for various conditions:

```
Select Top 10
  c.userdef1,
  c.userdef2,
  c.userdef3,
  c.userdef4,
  c_2.userdef13,
  c_3.userdef50,
  c_4.userdef28,
from dbo.c_5_table as c_5
inner join dbo.c_table as c
  on c.pk = c_5.pk
inner join dbo.c_3_table as c_3
  on c_3.pk=c.pk
inner join dbo.c_4_table as c_4
  on c_4.pk = c.pk
inner join dbo.c_2_table as c_2
  on c_2.pk = c.pk 
where c_5.phone = '1234567890'
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: No `ORDER BY` no guaranteed order. Add that with a `TOP` and SQL Server is free to return any arbitrary rows it wants.

Comment: @Larnu thanks. And you know why sql behave like this?

Comment: Because you didn't tell SQL Server what order you wanted the data. If you don't tell SQL Server what order you want the data, then I can't read your mind, and will just return 10 arbitrary rows. You would do the same in real life if someone just asked you to give them 5 apples, and there were 10 on the table.